# TypeError: Event constructor: Argument 2 can't be converted to a dictionary

Tags: reactjs, time-series, bar-chart, timeserieschart, real-time-data

I can't set up a BarChart for real time using pondjs/react-timeseries-charts.

I try to use Event class like in the [example](http://software.es.net/react-timeseries-charts/#/example/realtime).

When I set the constructor like, for instance:

```
new Event( new Date(), 15 );
```

I get the error
"TypeError: Event constructor: Argument 2 can't be converted to a dictionary."

I don't see the problem as the [documentation](https://doc.esdoc.org/github.com/esnet/pond/class/src/event.js%7EEvent.html) says that "The data may be any type.".

The [source code related](https://github.com/esnet/react-timeseries-charts/blob/master/src/website/packages/charts/examples/realtime/Index.js) with the example puzzles me more as it uses TimeEvent instead of Event. BTW, trying to use TimeEvent gives the same error.

Comment: Have you tried new Event( new Date(), {value: 15} );

Comment: If I do so, I get a new error message: "TypeError: Cannot construct Event instances directly"

Comment: How about -->  new TimeEvent( new Date(),  {value: 15} );  Is there a reason you are using Event instead of TimeEvent.

Comment: My only reason is my ignorance. In the concept explanation they use "Event" while in the source code they provide for this explanation they use "TimeEvent"... I'm confused.

Comment: Using: new TimeEvent( new Date(), {value: 15} );      avoided the error... thanks!

Comment: Post the answer I will accept